# The css style I have written for div element seems at screen without any div element at body section

Tags: html, css

I have written style for my div element and div element at body section. When the code runs I see two div element at screen. Even when the body section is empty, the div seems at screen. I write on Visual Code. Please help me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p {
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    span {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>article 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi sit, omnis voluptatibus quasi exercitationem cupiditate reprehenderit quidem distinctio. Omnis <span>temporibus</span> necessitatibus illo deleniti quia reprehenderit aspernatur molestias
      rerum veniam quam!
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS that produces your issue?

Comment: Need to include code and be clearer in what you're asking

Comment: Fico can you include the html source code in your question? Otherwise it is difficult for us to understand your issue.

Comment: I tried and realized that my code works with other editor properly but it doesn't work correctly with Visual Code. How can I solve this problem??

Comment: What happens when you view it in a browser? Can you attach a screen of what you are seeing in VS Code?

Comment: @alasdair009, I don't have a right for sharing image by the site. I see two div on screen despite the fact that there's one div element in body section and when I remove div element from body section, I see empty div again( when body section is empty). If I change  border color of style, it chances at screen

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache related issue. Press "ctrl + shift + i", right click on the reload icon at the top left corner and select "Empty cache and hard reload". This MIGHT solve the issue.

Comment: Where do I have to press  "ctrl + shift + i" ??

Comment: In your browser.